# How do I do Wishlist Member authentication into a WordPress site from a non PHP application?

Tags: ios, swift, wordpress, authentication

I'm having problems when trying to do Wishlist Member authentication from an iOS Swift application. The goal is to retrieve the current users email address. I’ve tried to interpret this info: http://codex.wishlistproducts.com/tutorial-authenticating-with-the-wishlist-member-api-from-a-non-php-application-ios-android-netetc/,  but keep getting "success" :0, "ERROR_CODE" :65537, "ERROR" : "Access denied - Invalid authentication”. First step works, i.e. I’m able to get the “lock” cookie. I’m using SwiftHash for MD5. This is what I'm doing:

1) Run auth command in order to get the “lock” cookie.

```
http://content.xxxxxxxx.com/?/wlmapi/2.0/json/auth
```

This works fine and I get a lock cookie.

2) Then I run the following request using the API key and the “lock” cookie

```
let lock = self.getWLMAPILock(). // retrieve lock cookie
let key = “xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx” // key removed for security
let newString = “\(lock)\(key)”  // concatenate the two strings
let newKey = MD5(newString).     // create auth_key
let postString = ("key=\(newKey),support_emulation=1")
let postData = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
let request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: “http://content.xxxxxxxx.com/?/wlmapi/2.0/json/auth")!)
request.httpMethod = “POST"
request.httpBody = postData
otiWebview.loadRequest((request as NSMutableURLRequest) as URLRequest)
```

This generates an error: "success" :0, "ERROR_CODE" :65537, "ERROR" : "Access denied - Invalid authentication"

3) Run request with url:

```
http://content.xxxxxxxx.com/?/wlmapi/2.0/json/members
```

Not run yet.

Comment: I know this is an old question but I am having a similar problem in Android.

I have a Cookie Jar setup, and the post to the /auth end point is returning the auth cookie just fine, in the format:

`md5(‘WLMAPI2’ . $auth_key)`
However, whenever I run a call to the GET /members endpoint I get every time the following error, even though this auth cookie is being sent to this page:

`{"success":0,"ERROR_CODE":65536,"ERROR":"Access Denied - Not authenticated"}`
Did you have the same issue?

Comment: @JossStuart I remember that it was a lot of errors and testing over and over, but I can't remember if I had that exact issue. You just need to be persistent and read the instructions carefully. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! The above scheme is basically correct, just had to add

`let newKey = MD5(newString).lowercased()`